# simulation of an attitude optimal Backstepping controller based quaternion for a UAV in MATLAB

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, simulation, matlab, optimal-control

I'am trying to implement this open access research article [Attitude Optimal Backstepping Controller Based Quaternion for a UAV](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2016/8573235/)

I did not find the same result in this paper Can anyone tell me where my error is in this code

**Case 1**. Let the initial condition of the quaternion error be $\mathrm{Q}_{e0}= (0.8224, 0.2226, 0.4397, 0.3604)^{T}$, which corresponds to an angle $\phi(0) = 34.67^{\circ}$; the matrices $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are computed through Riccati equation and $\gamma_{2}$ is chosen to achieve good performances. For that case $q_{0}(0) >0$ and will be stabilized to 1. Figures 1, 2, and 3 show the attitude responses and the control inputs, which gives a convergence in short time. These results are nearby the normal reflect when analyzing the initial location of $\phi$ which lies in the first quadrant.

```
function xdot = test(x)
R1=0.1*eye(3,3);
v=[0.0098,0.0098,0.0176];
J=diag(v);
R2=0.03*eye(3,3);
gamma= 150;
Q1=eye(3,3);
Q2=eye(3,3);
W_d=[0.56;0.61;0.42];
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
R_T=[ x(1)^2+x(2)^2-x(3)^2-x(4)^2, 2*(x(2)*x(3)+x(1)*x(4)), 2*(x(2)*x(4)-x(1)*x(3))   
          2*(x(2)*x(3)-x(1)*x(4)), x(1)^2-x(2)^2+x(3)^2-x(4)^2, 2*(x(3)*x(4)+x(1)*x(2))   
          2*(x(2)*x(4)+x(1)*x(3)), 2*(x(3)*x(4)-x(1)*x(2)), x(1)^2-x(2)^2-x(3)^2+x(4)^2];
W_star=R_T*W_d;
q0=x(1);
qv=[x(2);x(3);x(4)];
W_aux=[x(5);x(6);x(7)];

B1=0.5*[0,x(4),-x(3);-x(4),0,x(2);x(3),-x(2),0]+q0*eye(3,3);
B2=inv(J);
A2=(-inv(J)*[0,x(7),-x(6);-x(7),0,x(5);x(6),-x(5),0]*J-inv(J)*[0,W_star(3),-W_star(2);-W_star(3),0,W_star(1);W_star(2),-W_star(1),0]*J);
G2=inv(J);
B22=inv(J);
z1=[x(8);x(9);x(10)];
z2=[x(11);x(12);x(13)];
p1=[x(14) x(15) x(16);x(17) x(18) x(19);x(20) x(21) x(22)];
p2=[x(23) x(24) x(25);x(26) x(27) x(28);x(29) x(30) x(31)];
W2=1/(2*gamma^2)*B22'*p2*z2;
Ksi2=-inv(R2)*B2'*p2*z2;

v1=-inv(R1)*inv(B1)*inv(R1)*p1*qv*sign(q0);
q0dot=-0.5*qv'*W_aux;
qvdot=B1*W_aux;
B1dot=0.5*[0,-qvdot(3),qvdot(2);qvdot(3),0,-qvdot(1);-qvdot(2),qvdot(1),0]+q0dot*eye(3,3);
p1dot=p1*B1*inv(R1)*B1'*p1-Q1;
v1dot=inv((B1^2*R1^2))*(B1*p1*qvdot + B1*p1dot*qv - p1*B1dot*qv)*sign(q0);
%v1dot=-inv(R1)*invB1dot*inv(R1)*p1*x1+(-inv(R1)*inv(B1)*inv(R1))*(p1dot*x1+p1*x1dot);
v2=inv(R2)*B2'*p2*z2+inv(B2)*v1dot*sign(q0)-inv(B2)*A2*v1*sign(q0)+inv(B2)*inv(p2)*B1'*p1*z1-inv(B2)*(1/2*gamma^2)*B22*(B22')*p2*z2;
W_auxdot=A2*W_aux+B2*v2+G2*W2;
z1dot=B1*z2-B1*inv(R1)*B1'*p1*z1;
z2dot=A2*z2+B2*Ksi2-inv(p2)*B1'*p1*z1;
p1dot=p1dot(:);
T2=1/(2*gamma^2)*G2*(G2')-B2*inv(R2)*B2';
p2dot=-A2'*p2-p2*A2-p2*T2*p2-Q2;
p2dot=p2dot(:);
xdot=[q0dot;qvdot;W_auxdot;z1dot;z2dot;p1dot;p2dot];
xdot=xdot(:);
end
```

execute function

```
% test for function deri
clc;clear ALL;close all;
[t,x]=ode45(@(t,x)test(x),[0 1],[0.8224 0.2226 0.4397 0.3604 0 0 0 1 0.5 3 2 1 1.2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.01 0.02 0.3 0.4 0.2 0.03 0.02 0.001 0.4])
```

Comment: Do you *really* expect anyone here to spend hours of their own time reading the paper and working through your very long post? Try contacting the authors of the paper - but you will need to give them more information than "my code doesn't work!"

Comment: @alephzero - OP just copied the paper in the post. Since the paper is already linked, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

That is quite the wall of text. You don't need to rewrite an entire academic paper to ask a question (**please** don't). You failed to *show* what it is you thought you were supposed to get or what you actually got.

That said, I think your quaternion to rotation matrix equation is not correct. It looks like maybe it only works for unit quaternions. The quaternion errors you're passing in are not.